# algebra substitution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Evaluate $\frac{x}{yz} + \frac{y}{xz} + \frac{z}{y}$ given that $x + y + z = 4$ and $xyz = -60$ and $xy + xz + yz = −17$.

I made this expression have a common denominator $\frac{x}{yz} + \frac{y}{xz} + \frac{z}{y}$, which turned out to be $xyz=-60$. However, I tried using all other combinations for the two other formulas but nothing worked

Comment: Are you sure, that there is $\frac{z}{y}$, not $\frac{z}{xy}$?

Comment: Not sure if this will be useful, but the sums/products are coefficients of a cubic. Again, not sure if that observation is helpful is any way...

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak You must be right, because only then there is a unique result.

Answer (score 0):

Subsituting $z=4-x-y$ we obtain th following two equations:

$$
 - x^2 - xy + 4x - y^2 + 4y + 17=0
$$

$$
- x^2y - xy^2 + 4xy + 60=0
$$
Taking resultants we see that $(x,y)=(-4,3),(-4,5),(3,-4),(3,5),(5,-4),(5,3)$. Then we have
$$
\frac{x}{yz} + \frac{y}{xz} + \frac{z}{y}=\frac{5}{4},\frac{-1}{12},\ldots,
$$
but much nicer, **always**
$$
\frac{x}{yz} + \frac{y}{xz} + \frac{z}{xy}=-\frac{5}{6}
$$